# A script causes a parent script to stop

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, interactive

I have a third-party script that runs some complicated stuff.

I run everything from an ssh session (the machine is a headless VM running Ubuntu 20.04).

When I run it interactively, it runs normally.

```
$ ./third-party-script.sh one
<script output one>
$ ./third-party-script.sh two
<script output two>
```

When I run it from another script, the parent script stops when the third-party script executes for the *second* time.

```
$ cat my-script.sh
#!/bin/sh
./third-party-script.sh one
./third-party-script.sh two
$
$ ./my-script.sh
<script output one>
[1]+  Stopped                 ./my-script.sh
$
```

I can send my script to foreground and it continues normally

```
$ fg
<script output two>
$
```

What could be the reason of this behaviour and how can it be avoided? I cannot fix the third-party script or anything that it runs, I can only fix my script. (The original "my-script" is written in Python and uses `os.system`, I simplified it to a bare-bones shell script for this question).

I tried running the script with `nohup` but it didn't help.

Thanks to @ilkkachu, I have narrowed it down to the third-party script executing `bash -ic some_command`. So the minimal script that reproduces this in *my* environment is:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash -ic ls
bash -ic ls
```

`sh -ic` and `bash -c` both fix the problem. Unfortunately I cannot change the command. I need to *wrap* the third-party script somehow so that it stops doing this.

I tried `bash -icx` instead, but this doesn't narrow down the problem any further. The second `bash` execution stops before printing any command.

I tried to `strace -f` the whole thing and this is what comes in the end:

```
[pid 3805453] ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [3805322]) = 0
[pid 3805453] rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f131f36a090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f131f36a090}, 8) = 0
[pid 3805453] kill(0, SIGTTIN)          = 0
[pid 3805321] <... wait4 resumed>0x7ffcc2d45bfc, 0, NULL) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 3805453] --- SIGTTIN {si_signo=SIGTTIN, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3805453, si_uid=4437} ---
[pid 3805321] --- SIGTTIN {si_signo=SIGTTIN, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3805453, si_uid=4437} ---
[pid 3805453] --- stopped by SIGTTIN ---
[pid 3805321] --- stopped by SIGTTIN ---
```

3805453 is the *second* child bash running `-ic ls` and 3805321 is the top-level bash running `my-script.sh`.

It is the only line with `kill(0, SIGTTIN)` in the strace log. The first child `bash` doesn't do anything like that, only the second one does.

Comment: We can't really help without knowing what the scripts do. Can you try and give us a reproducible example? Try removing lines from the third party script until you find the simplest version that reproduces the problem and then share that here. Also, if this is not your actual script, please show us your script. Unless this simple shell version also reproduces the problem. Does it?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot open the third-party thing. The simple my-script.sh also reproduces the problem just like the real Python script. I can try and add say signal handling to it in in order to narrow down the problem, but I don't really know what to do exactly.

Comment: if that third-party script is a shell script, you could run it manually with `xtrace`/`set -x` enabled to have the shell print the commands it executes, so you'd see what triggers the stop. Check the hashbang line to see which shell it uses and if there are any options, e.g. if there's `#!/bin/bash -e`, you'd need  `bash -ex ./third-party-script.sh` . Or if you can edit it temporarily to add `set -x` at the start, that would also work.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ahh I narrowed it down to the third-party script executing `bash -ic some_command`. The parent script stops at that point.

Comment: @n.m. that seems really weird. `bash -i` opens a new shell session and `bash -c` runs a command. I am having trouble understanding why the two would be combined, but one reason might be to read the user's interactive shell initialization files. So there might be something in your `~/.bashrc` affecting it. Can you try running the script as a different user (one with no `.bashrc`) or if that's not an option, try renaming your `~/.bashrc` to something else and then running the script to see if you still get the problem or if the issue is indeed something in your bashrc?

Comment: @terdon yes, the intention of this `bash -ic` is clearly to read the user's startup files and execute a command in that environment, because the command may need it (it is actually supposed to be a user-supplied command, but I can reproduce the problem with just `ls`.).  I did try to rename my `.bashrc` (and also `.profile` for a good measure) but it didn't help, it still stops at executing the second `bash`.

Comment: There is something you are not telling us. Running from cron?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I would love to figure out what it is! No, not running from cron., running from normal ssh.

Comment: ssh! Please add that to your question, that is very relevant since it directly affects your environment.

Comment: @terdon done, but I have no idea how it can affect the environment...

Comment: No, you're right. I can reproduce this with your simple `ls` script without ssh. I was hoping the ssh which affects what files are read when you log in would be affecting it.